# update column with concatenating for that group only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2014

I have to concatenate items purchased by every customer before a date

Scenario now

```
Date   CustomerID ItemID PreviousItems
9/9/19 C1         I1     NULL
8/8/19 C1         I2     NULL
7/7/19 C1         I3     NULL
6/6/19 C1         I4     NULL
9/9/19 C2         I5     NULL
8/8/19 C2         I1     NULL
7/7/19 C2         I4     NULL
```

Desired Output

```
Date   CustomerID ItemID PreviousItems
9/9/19 C1         I1     I2,I3,I4
8/8/19 C1         I2     I3,I4
7/7/19 C1         I3     I4
6/6/19 C1         I4     NULL
9/9/19 C2         I5     I1,I4
8/8/19 C2         I1     I4
7/7/19 C2         I4     NULL
```

I have tried this code but did not work

as I did not know where to group by customer id!

```
update a
  set PreviousItems = COALESCE(PreviousItems+ ', ', '') + ItemID 
from Purchase a
```

How can I update with group by?

Comment: If you are able to use SQL Server 2017, you can try the STRING_AGG function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I guessing the data show is the data you have now.. can you show your desired output?

Comment: @Harry this is the desired output. the data I have now has PreviousItems = NULL for all records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use STRING_AGG.
I know you think you are on SqlServer 2014, and STRING_AGG is not available there, but there a number of references as to how to simulate it.  This site says Postgres, but a SQL Server function would work the same way:

https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/10001/Aggregate-String-Concatenation-in-SQL-Server-2012-like-stringagg-in-PostgreSql/5122#.XVYSJuhKhaQ

```
SELECT p1.dt, p1.customerId, p1.itemId, 
       (SELECT STRING_AGG(pPast.ItemID, ',')
        FROM Purchase pPast
        WHERE pPast.customerId = p1.customerId
          AND pPast.dt < p1.dt) as PreviousItems
FROM Purchase p1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `INNER JOIN` to `UPDATE` `[PreviousItems]` column of the table by considering `FOR XML` method within the auxiliary query as :

```
update t
    set t.[PreviousItems]=right(q.data,len(q.data)-1)
   from tab as t
   join (
select t1.[Date], t1.[CustomerID],
       stuff((select distinct ',' + t2.[ItemID]
                from tab t2
               where t2.[Date]<t1.[Date]
                 and t1.[CustomerID] = t2.[CustomerID]  for xml path(''), type
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') data
  from tab t1
 group by t1.[CustomerID], t1.[Date]
) q on  t.[Date]=q.[Date] and t.[CustomerID]=q.[CustomerID];
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f343659c9c66ecb267de448575a8fcba)</kbd>